# Unity2D: Panning a map using touch still register even a button in canvas is tapped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a problem cancelling pan feature of my app when a button in HUD is pressed.

We're using canvas for displaying UIs, so I can't use the RayCast to detect if a touch hit a button or not since the button is not directly in the world where the map to be panned located.

I already added collider to the buttons and tried printing the name of objects hitted by raycast but it just passes through the buttons like they are not there.

How am I suppose to detect if a button in canvas is touched so I can cancel executing pan feature?

Answer (score 0):

Check EventSystem's [IsPointerOverGameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.BaseInputModule.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) method. You can use it like this:

```
public bool IsPointerOverUI
{
    get{
        return EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import `UnityEngine.EventSystems`